# UIButton inside tableviewcell triggers cell instead of button

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uibutton

I have a `UITableViewCell` with a button inside of it. (made through IB).

Now what I'd like to do is the following:

1. When pressing the `UITableViewCell`, I'd like to trigger a `segue`.
2. When pressing the `UIButton`, I'd like to trigger an action.

However, what actually happens is that the `UITableViewCell` gets selected when the button is pressed, instead of the desired result.

Is there a way around it that enables both actions at the same time?

Thanks.

-- Edit

I'd like to be able to select the table cell still, AND be able to press the button. So disabling selection wouldn't work.

-- As requested, the code for the `cellForRowAt:` method

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: PersonTableViewCell.identifier, for: indexPath) as! PersonTableViewCell

    if ( indexPath.row < (self.searchResult.count)) {
        cell.configure(searchResult[indexPath.row])
    }

    return cell
}
```

Then, inside of the configure function of the `cell`, a `UITapGestureRecognizer` is created on the button that triggers the following function:

```
func follow(profile: User) {
    self.followButton.isSelected = !self.followButton.isSelected
    profile.toggleFollow(callback: { _ in })
}
```

Comment: @the4kman i edited the question.

Answer (score 3):

Ensure following points for your button inside cell.

1. User interaction for is enabled for your button
2. Button has proper frame size (tappable area)
3. A valid button action is assigned/connected to button
4. Button is top most view (there is no other view covering button)

Show your code for `cellForRow(atIndex...` and your table view cell class to get exact solution.

Here is sample code:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell") as! CustomCell
    cell.yourbutton.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    cell.yourbutton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.buttonTapped(sender:)), for: UIControlEvents.touchUpInside)

    //cell.bringSubview(toFront: cell.yourbutton)
    //cell.contentView.bringSubview(toFront: cell.yourbutton)

    return cell
}


@objc func buttonTapped(sender: UIButton) {
    print("button tapped")
}
```

Edit: Button has its own control actions/events handler. You may not need to add `UITapGestureRecognizer`.

Comment: I've added the code you requested.